# ARRAYs returns from function

Tags: php, arrays

I'm just learn PHP, so sorry about this probably simple question..

PHP code cannot return values from the function "bubble_sort".

I have 3 arrays.

$filesmtime: Files Modified Time

```
Array ( [0] => 1419242709 [1] => 1428634648 [2] => 1428604291 [3] => 1428500914 [4] => 1428551552 [5] => 1428459515 [6] => 1428614848 [7] => 1428633569 [8] => 1428450275 [9] => 1428486035 [10] => 1428909099 [11] => 1428506793 .....
```

$files: File path names

```
Array ( [0] => ./reports/2014/12/10038.png [1] => ./reports/2015/04/10404.png [2] => ./reports/2015/04/10151.png .....
```

$filesfname: File names

```
Array ( [0] => 10038.png [1] => 10404.png [2] => 10151.png [3] => 11346.png [4] => 11768.png [5] => 11001.png [6] => 10239.png [7] => 10395.png [8] => 10924.png .....
```

Code is:

```
function bubble_sort($arr, $arr2, $arr3) {
  $size = count($arr);
  for ($i=0; $i<$size; $i++) {
    for ($j=0; $j<$size-1-$i; $j++) {
      if ($arr[$j+1] < $arr[$j]) {
        swap($arr, $j, $j+1);
        swap($arr2, $j, $j+1);
        swap($arr3, $j, $j+1);
      }
    }
  }
  return array('ar1'=>$arr, 'ar2'=>$arr2, 'ar3'=>$arr3);
}

function swap(&$arr, $a, $b) {
  $tmp = $arr[$a];
  $arr[$a] = $arr[$b];
  $arr[$b] = $tmp;
}


$arrs = bubble_sort($filesmtime, $files, $filesfname);

echo $arrs['ar1'];
echo $arrs['ar2'];
echo $arrs['ar3'];
```

Comment: You need to put a `,` between each array element. Is that a typing mistake  over here?

Comment: Code starting from "function bubble_sort", so there is not array element in the code... Thank you

Comment: @hasanoa What does $arrs contain after calling bubble_sort? Put a print_r($arrs) after that.

Comment: Is there any error that you get? I tried your code with some sample data. It is returning the arrays.

Comment: Dani Dudas, Thank you for your replay. I tried print_r($arrs); line, but nothing happened.

Comment: Prerak Sola, if i add a line   echo "hello"; at the top of the code. hello occurs in browser. No error code...

Comment: `var_dump` all three arrays before `$arrs = bubble_sort($filesmtime, $files, $filesfname);` What do you get then?

Comment: Thank you Prerak Sola,  var_dump($filesmtime); returns  array(1959) { [0]=> int(1419242709) [1]=> int(1428634648) [2]=> int(1428604291) [3]=> int(1428500914) [4]=> int(1428551552) [5]=> int(1428459515)........    var_dump($files); returns   array(1959) { [0]=> string(32) "./reports/2014/12/10038.png" [1]=> string(32) "./reports/2015/04/10404.png" [2]=> string(32) "./reports/2015/04/10151.png"...........   var_dump($filesfname); returns   array(1959) { [0]=> string(14) "10038.png" [1]=> string(14) "10404.png" [2]=> string(14) "10151.png"..........

Comment: Use `var_dump` instead of `echo` when you output the contents of the `$arr` array. What do you get than?

Comment: thank you for your reply

$arrs = bubble_sort($filesmtime, $files, $filesfname);

echo $arrs['ar1'];
echo $arrs['ar2'];
echo $arrs['ar3'];



echo $arrs['ar1']; returns nothing

echo $arrs['ar2']; returns nothing

echo $arrs['ar3']; returns nothing

Comment: use `var_dump( $arrs['ar1']);` Does that return anything?

Comment: I tried something...
I removed these lines: swap($arr2, $j, $j+1);  swap($arr3, $j, $j+1); then 
var_dump( $arrs['ar1']); returns sorted array. It is ok. But I want to sort other 2 arrays ($arr2 and $arr3) at the same time $arr1. How can I do this?

Comment: I tried another code. Problem's over

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error lies here

```
return array('ar1'=>'$arr', 'ar2'=>'$arr2', 'ar3'=>'$arr3');
```

it should be

```
return array('ar1'=>$arr, 'ar2'=>$arr2, 'ar3'=>$arr3);
```

Comment: ok, I just tried 2 of these versions. '$arr1' version was just for string, not array. I forgot remove ' ' characters before past the code here... Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I tried another code as follows. Problem's over..
Thank you Prerak Sola,Dani Dudas and mariobgr

```
function bubble_sort($arr, $arr2, $arr3) {
  $size = count($arr);
  for ($i=0; $i<$size; $i++) {
    for ($j=0; $j<$size-1-$i; $j++) {
      if ($arr[$j+1] < $arr[$j]) {
           $tmp = $arr[$j];
           $arr[$j] = $arr[$j+1];
           $arr[$j+1] = $tmp;
           $tmp2 = $arr2[$j];
           $arr2[$j] = $arr2[$j+1];
           $arr2[$j+1] = $tmp2;
           $tmp3 = $arr3[$j];
           $arr3[$j] = $arr3[$j+1];
           $arr3[$j+1] = $tmp3;
      }
    }
  }
  return array('ar1'=>$arr, 'ar2'=>$arr2, 'ar3'=>$arr3);
}


$arrs = bubble_sort($filesmtime, $files, $filesfname);

var_dump($arrs['ar1']);
var_dump($arrs['ar2']);
var_dump($arrs['ar3']);
```